# unable to cascade or title horizontal ChildForms on Panel Control of mdi parent form using LayoutMdi

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have multiple child forms on Panel control of MDI parent Form. I can open child forms form1, form2 and so on use below method

```
Private Sub ShowChildForm(Of Myform As {Form, New})()
    Try
        Dim childForm As Form = PanelPrinciple.Controls.OfType(Of Myform)().FirstOrDefault()
        If childForm Is Nothing Then
            childForm = New Myform()
            childForm.MdiParent = Me
            childForm.Parent = PanelPrinciple
            PanelContent.Controls.Add(childForm)
            PanelContent.Tag = childForm
            childForm.Show()
            childForm.BringToFront()
        Else
            childForm.BringToFront()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

I want to Cascade and Tile Horizontal all opened child forms using LayoutMdi as below which is not working.

```
LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileHorizontal)
```

I would like to seek for help here.
it would be appreciated if anyone could help and advice me.
Thank you.

Comment: `PanelContent.Controls.Add(childForm)` it's not an MDI child, apparently it's a child form hosted in a panel.

Comment: If i do not add this, form1, form2 are not displayed inside the panel. anyway i can achieve it? thanks

Comment: MDI is different from hosting forms in panel. What's the requirement here?

Comment: I have a main form (MDIForm), on top of main form i place two panels one is for menu item and another one is to display child form1, form2 and so on. the thing is that I am not able to arrange form1, form2 and form3 in the panel.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't the the point. MDI (using MDI parent and MDI Childern) is totally different from showing forms in a panel.

Comment: I am sorry sir for stupid question. I am don't know how can achieve to display and arrange forms in panel.